# Python - creating two sharing y axis for double y subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Currently, I have the first y axis (probability) of my subplots aligned. However, I am attempting to get the secondary y axis (sample size) of the subplots aligned. I've tried to simply set the y-axis limit, but this solution isn't very generalizable.

Here is my code:

```
attacks = 5
crit_rate = .5

idealdata = fullMatrix(attacks, crit_rate)
crit_rate = ("crit_%.0f" % (crit_rate*100))
actualdata = trueDataM(attacks, crit_rate)
[enter image description here][1]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(attacks+1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axs2 = [ax.twinx() for ax in axs]

fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'State', ha='center')
fig.text(0.04, 0.5, 'Probability', va='center', rotation='vertical')
fig.text(.95, .5, 'Sample Size', va='center', rotation='vertical')
fig.text(.45, .9, 'Ideal vs. Actual Critical Strike Rate', va='center')
cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
samplesize = datasample(attacks, 'crit_50')
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
for i in range(attacks+1):
    axs[i].plot(idealdata[i], color=cmap(i/attacks), marker='o', lw=3)
    axs[i].plot(actualdata[i], 'gray', marker='o', lw=3, ls='--')
    axs2[i].bar(range(len(samplesize[i])), samplesize[i], width=.1, color=cmap(i/attacks), alpha = .6)

plt.show()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKJlE.png

Comment: Can you make that an [mcve]? Are you asking how to programaticaly determine the scale of the second y axis? What would the criteria be?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to have the second y axes (right side) of the subplots be the same. So far, the first y axis (left side) is the same.

Comment: `the same` as what?

Comment: Each of the y-axes on the left side share the same axis. The y-axes on the right side are not the same. Some range from 0-30 while some range from 0-400. I'm trying to figure out a way so that all the y-axes on the right side all have the same range.

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question, especially if that data is from an external/unreachable resource.  the easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - If you read with a critical eye, that is included/implied in [mcve]. You have three data sets you are plotting t would be useful to have a minimal example of each in your question.

Comment: Matplotlib is great - I recommend working through the [Tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html) - through the Legend Guide at least, you don't need to memorize them but it will give you a good feel for how it works and make things easier to find in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without data to confirm my assumptions it's hard to tell if this will be correct. 
You are not making any attempt to scale the left y-axes so that data must all have the same range. To ensure the right y-axes all have the same scale/limits you need to determine the range (max and min) of the (all) data being plotted on those axes then apply that to all of them.

It isn't clear whether `samplesize` is a Numpy ndarray or a lists of lists, I'm also assuming that it is a 2-d structure with `range(attacks+1)` *rows*. Since you are making bar charts on the second y-axes you only need to find the largest *`height`* in all the data.

```
# for a list of lists
biggest = max(max(row) for row in samplesize)
# or
biggest = max(map(max,samplesize))

# for an ndarray
biggest = samplesize.max()
```

Then apply that scale to all the right y-axes before they are *shown*

```
for ax in axs2:
    ax.set_ylim(top=biggest)
```

If you determine `biggest` prior to the plot loop you can just add a line to that loop:

```
for i in range(attacks+1):
    ...
    axs2[i].set_ylim(top=biggest)
```

---

You'll find plenty of related SO Q&A'a searching with the terms: `matplotlib subplots same y scale`, `matplotlib subplots y axis limits` or something similar.

---

Here is a toy example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
lines = np.random.randint(0,200,(5,10))
bars = [np.random.randint(0,np.random.randint(0,10000),10) for _ in (0,0,0,0,0,)]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(lines.shape[0], sharex=True, sharey=True)
axs2 = [ax.twinx() for ax in axs]
#xs = np.arange(lines.shape[1])
xs = np.arange(1,11)
biggest = max(map(max,bars))
for ax,ax2,line,row in zip(axs,axs2,lines,bars):
    bars = ax2.bar(xs,row)
    ax.plot(line)
    ax2.set_ylim(top=biggest)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```